# How to login on divshot cli inside a vagrant box?

Tags: authentication, vagrant, divshot

[Divshot](https://divshot.com) has a nice command line interface. The first thing you should do after installing it with npm is to login.

```
divshot login
```

It should open a browser tab/window, you login on the divshot website and you authorise the CLI client by pressing a button at the end of the process.

But I have all my development environment on a vagrant box. When I type "divshot login" nothing happens. No browser tab appears.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run "divshot login" from your command line on you local machine and
   follow the instructions to login.
2. Run "divshot auth:token" to get
   your auth token from the command line.
3. When running commands that
   interact with the Divshot API, use the flag "--token " to
   give it authorization (on the vagrant box)

Comment: It would be nice if I could login inside the vagrant box. Adding --token all the time is not fun.. but... this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

1. Run `divshot login` on your local computer
2. Inspect `$HOME/.divshot/config/user.json`, check it has a key `token`
3. Copy that file to the corresponding path on the other computer